# pathParameters documentation exception (urlTemplate not found)

Tags: java, spring-restdocs

When using `pathParameters` to document the URI path parameters like below

```
@Test
public void documentGetRouteById() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/route/{id}", "FooBar")).andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andDo(document("api-getRouteById",
                    pathParameters(parameterWithName("id").description("die Routen ID"))));
}
```

I get the following excpetion

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: urlTemplate not found. Did you use RestDocumentationRequestBuilders to build the request?
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.request.PathParametersSnippet.extractUrlTemplate(PathParametersSnippet.java:95)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.request.PathParametersSnippet.extractActualParameters(PathParametersSnippet.java:82)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.request.AbstractParametersSnippet.verifyParameterDescriptors(AbstractParametersSnippet.java:77)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.request.AbstractParametersSnippet.createModel(AbstractParametersSnippet.java:65)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.request.PathParametersSnippet.createModel(PathParametersSnippet.java:67)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.TemplatedSnippet.document(TemplatedSnippet.java:64)
    at org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.RestDocumentationResultHandler.handle(RestDocumentationResultHandler.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andDo(MockMvc.java:158)
```

I am pretty sure I did the test setup like explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/#getting-started-documentation-snippets-setup).

What could I probably have done wrong?

(Spring REST docs version is 1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The exception message is trying to point you in the right direction:

> urlTemplate not found. Did you use RestDocumentationRequestBuilders to build the request?

You need to use `RestDocumentationRequestBuilders` so that Spring REST Docs can capture the URL and extract the parameters from it. This is [mentioned in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/#documenting-your-api-path-parameters) where it says:

> To make the path parameters available for documentation, the request must be built using one of the methods on RestDocumentationRequestBuilders rather than MockMvcRequestBuilders.

Replacing your static import of `MockMvcRequestBuilders.get` with one for `RestDocumentationRequestBuilders.get` should resolve the problem.

Comment: So you say it is all written down? You're right! Well documented module. The problem was once again in front of the monitor.